# Redis server throwing a Background serving error

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, redis

it is showing like this in redis server after 20 to 30 mins. the first 20 to 30 mins it is working fine only but after that it is throwing this error.so please help me to solve this[you can see the image in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlUy5.png)

```
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:21.293 # Background saving error
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:27.016 * 1 changes in 3600 seconds. Saving...
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:27.025 * Background saving started by pid 9044
[9044] 24 Jun 19:06:27.147 # Failed opening .rdb for saving: Permission denied
[9044] 24 Jun 19:06:27.148 # rdbSave failed in qfork: Permission denied
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:27.230 # fork operation complete
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:27.231 # Background saving error
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:33.060 * 1 changes in 3600 seconds. Saving...
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:33.063 * Background saving started by pid 11396
[11396] 24 Jun 19:06:33.192 # Failed opening .rdb for saving: Permission denied
[11396] 24 Jun 19:06:33.193 # rdbSave failed in qfork: Permission denied
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:33.264 # fork operation complete
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:33.265 # Background saving error
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:39.034 * 1 changes in 3600 seconds. Saving...
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:39.043 * Background saving started by pid 10516
[10516] 24 Jun 19:06:39.183 # Failed opening .rdb for saving: Permission denied
[10516] 24 Jun 19:06:39.185 # rdbSave failed in qfork: Permission denied
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:39.245 # fork operation complete
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:39.246 # Background saving error
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:45.073 * 1 changes in 3600 seconds. Saving...
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:45.083 * Background saving started by pid 1704
[1704] 24 Jun 19:06:45.219 # Failed opening .rdb for saving: Permission denied
[1704] 24 Jun 19:06:45.221 # rdbSave failed in qfork: Permission denied
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:45.289 # fork operation complete
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:45.290 # Background saving error
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:51.018 * 1 changes in 3600 seconds. Saving...
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:51.027 * Background saving started by pid 13012
[13012] 24 Jun 19:06:51.150 # Failed opening .rdb for saving: Permission denied
[13012] 24 Jun 19:06:51.152 # rdbSave failed in qfork: Permission denied
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:51.230 # fork operation complete
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:51.232 # Background saving error
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:57.049 * 1 changes in 3600 seconds. Saving...
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:57.053 * Background saving started by pid 1272
[1272] 24 Jun 19:06:57.177 # Failed opening .rdb for saving: Permission denied
[1272] 24 Jun 19:06:57.178 # rdbSave failed in qfork: Permission denied
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:57.253 # fork operation complete
[2476] 24 Jun 19:06:57.255 # Background saving error
[2476] 24 Jun 19:07:03.066 * 1 changes in 3600 seconds. Saving...
[2476] 24 Jun 19:07:03.075 * Background saving started by pid 13052
[13052] 24 Jun 19:07:03.208 # Failed opening .rdb for saving: Permission denied
[13052] 24 Jun 19:07:03.210 # rdbSave failed in qfork: Permission denied
[2476] 24 Jun 19:07:03.278 # fork operation complete
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the redis-server process does not have permission to open the .rdb file. Just run redis-server as an administrator on windows, it might solve your problem.